# Why is MySQL rejecting the following query?

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE table_one 
   SET user_accessible = 1 
 WHERE volume == 2 
   AND lesson_order == '04' 
 LIMIT 1
```

It's giving the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= '2' AND `lesson_order` == '04') LIMIT 1' at line 1

The query looks correct to me :(

Comment: Mysql also uses a single `=` in comparisons - you used double `==` in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks @Sirko,  pretty much used to `==` for comparisons.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Null safe equals in mysql is <=> not ==

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake on your comparison. Use single **=** not **==**

```
UPDATE table_one 
   SET user_accessible = 1 
 WHERE volume = 2
   AND lesson_order = '04' 
 LIMIT 1
```